# JS issue on Soundcloud API pausing sound

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

for some reason I can't fix this issue:

> if I click play,
>
> it plays if I click stop,
>
> it stops then
>
> If I click play again the sound resume then I click stop, **IT DOESN'T STOP**
>
> If I repeat again it stops the second time..

it basically it pauses only every other click... must be an easy fix but I can't get my head around it

here my code

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});

var Sstream;
var isOn = false;

function playTrack(myTrackId){ 
    console.log('isOn',isOn);
    if (isOn !== false) {
        Sstream.pause();
        isOn = false;
    } else {
        isOn = true;
        SC.stream("/tracks/" + myTrackId).then(function(sound){
            Sstream = sound;
            Sstream.play();
            Sstream.on('state-change', function (state) {
                 if (state == 'playing') {
                     isOn = true;
                 } else  if (state == 'pause'){
                     isOn = false;
                     Sstream.sound.pause();
                 } else  if (state == 'ended'){
                     isOn = false;
                     Sstream.sound.pause();
                 }
            });
        });
    }
}

$("#playTrack").click(function(){
    playTrack('123');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is right ?

```
Sstream.on('state-change', function (state) {
                 if (state == 'playing') {
                     isOn = true;
                 } else  if (state == 'pause'){
                     isOn = false;
                     Sstream.sound.pause();
                 } else  if (state == 'ended'){
                     isOn = false;
                     Sstream.sound.pause();
                 }
            });
```

It seems to me that on each state change you actually call pause which make another state changes, etc...
May be you need to make it only one pause ? so that you comment the 2  `Sstream.sound.pause();`